# How to page.click an element on a dynamic list that has a given value

Tags: puppeteer

Using puppeteer.js, I'm trying to automate selection (page.click) of an element with a given value of a dynamic list.
In the below code, the dynamic HTML show 3 companies. I want to select the one labeled "Company B".

```
<div id="ember1222" class="ao-list ember-view">
    <div data-test-company-list-row="true" class="list-item" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-1224="1224">
        <a href="#/manage-company/255/dashboard" id="ember1225" class="grid--nested ember-view">                        
            <div data-test-company-name="true" class="grid__cell">
                Company A
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div data-test-company-list-row="true" class="list-item" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-1224="1224">
        <a href="#/manage-company/256/dashboard" id="ember1228" class="grid--nested ember-view">                        
            <div data-test-company-name="true" class="grid__cell">
                Company B
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div data-test-company-list-row="true" class="list-item" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-1224="1224">
        <a href="#/manage-company/253/dashboard" id="ember1231" class="grid--nested ember-view">                        
                <div data-test-company-name="true" class="grid__cell">
                    Company C
                </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried getting the element location in an array:

```
async selectCompanyName(companyName) {
    // Wait for element to be rendered
    await page.waitForSelector('[data-test-company-name="true"]', { timeout: settings._30000 });

    // Create an array of Company Names
    let listCompanyNames = await page.evaluate(() => {
        let tds = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[data-test-company-name=="true"]'));
        return tds.map(td => td.textContent.trim());
    });

    // Find which row number the Company Name is on and click it
    let rowNumber = null;
    for (let i = 0; i < listCompanyNames.length; i++) {
        if (listCompanyNames[i] === companyName) {
            rowNumber = i;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I get the correct location in the array (i.e. 1), but then I'm not sure I know how to page.click it.
Ember has dynamic id's so I'm stick to using the HTML data- attribute.
I tried other approaches, like using the page.$$(), but I had no success.   Can any please assist me?

Answer (score 0):

`listCompanyNames` is list of string not element node, use `page.$$` to return element handle then you can use `click()`

```
async selectCompanyName(companyName) {
  // Wait for element to be rendered
  await page.waitForSelector('[data-test-company-name="true"]', {
    timeout: settings._30000
  });

  let listCompanyNames = await page.$$('[data-test-company-name=="true"]');

  for (let i = 0; i < listCompanyNames.length; i++) {
     let textContent = await page.evaluate(el => el.textContent, listCompanyNames[i]);
    // or
    //let textContent = await (await listCompanyNames[0].getProperty('textContent')).jsonValue()
    if (textContent === companyName) {
      rowNumber = i;
      listCompanyNames[i].click()
      break;
    }
  }
}
```